# Visual Studio 2013 include logical or in "find in files" (updated for VS2017)

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013, logical-or, findinfiles

How does one accomplish the following:

In Visual Studio 2013 include logical or in "find in files"

So I could do a search such as

```
http OR web
```

but the above syntax doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked in VS2017.

that's what you need to do

[image]

where \b is for matching the whole word

Answer (score 1):

A colleague pointed out the following regular expression:

The syntax is as following:  "Use Regular Expressions" checked, and search for:

```
(http) |  (https)
```

If anyone has a better way, please post.